# Joomla cache generation concurrency

Tags: php, caching, joomla, mutex, scalability

while inspecting joomla cache classes's code I've found that flock-based locking occures only when trying to access the cache file to read from it if the cache is available, or to write to  it if it's not.

Now, I'm facing this problem : 2 visitors hit the same page at the same time (1 second split), no cache is available, the first hit will :

-look for the file : no cache file available -> need to execute then cache to a file
-lock that new file
-execute some costly code
-write the results to the file
-unlock it and return the results

the second hit, 1 second later will :

-look for the file : no cache file available because the first PHP process (the 1's hit) is still busy generating data to write to the file -> so this PHP process decides to execute some code too and then cache it to a file (the same file)
-try to lock the file (it will wait until the 1st process finishes writing to it)
-re-execute that same costly code in vain
-write the results to the file again !
-unlock it and return the results

this precise scenario happens to me every time cache invalidates right in the middle of a load spike and make the website try to execute 10+ times the same code at the same time (wich does some heavy sql stuff) killing MySQL and doing more nasty stuff.

do you think like me that the locking must be smarter and prevent the regeneration of the same cache item many times in a row ? and if yes did anyone find how to correct this ? we kind of lost the benefit of caching at that precise moment ...

or is it like I'm missing something ?

Comment: Ummm… what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: it's j2.5, I think seriously about extending joomla classes and adding a flock() mutex/marker on an empty file just right the moment when the cache class decides to execute the code, if some other threa is in there wait then go read the freshly generated cache ...